# How to disconnect from wifi in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

i'm triying to make a simple app that just disconnect the actual wifi and dissable the reconection. Here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String networkSSID = "mySsid";
    String networkPass = "myNetPass";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";  
        conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
               wifiManager.disconnect();
               wifiManager.disableNetwork(i.networkId);
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the code works, got no errors, but my wifi is still connected, what can i do?

Comment: What is the purpose of `"\""`?

Comment: @cricket_007 It is needed for SSID and password to be `"example"`

Comment: Is your wifi configure by your app? If it is not, you cannot use `disableNetwork` on it as the Android will prevent that for security reason. (I think it is started from 5 or 6)

Comment: oh, did't know that was a security problem, then i just can disable if i configure the own connection by the app?